# IN clause from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code which allows using a variable within an IN clause:

```
    DECLARE @Ids varchar(50);
    SET @Ids = '24,25';

    SELECT * 
    FROM table
    WHERE ','+@Ids+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),id_field)+',%';
```

Since @Ids is an optional field which can be null, how would I modify the code such that it incorporates

```
    (@Ids IS NULL OR id_field = @Ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what you already have (*parenthesis added for readability*)

```
WHERE (@Ids IS NULL) OR (','+@Ids+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),id_field)+',%')
```

On a side note do realize that a query like this circumvents any index on `id_field` that might exist and will do a table scan to find matches.